# iframe dynamic height adjust

Tags: javascript

I am trying to adjust the height of the iframe when a user checks an input box (the checked input box expands a list).  I can not use ajax as a solution.  This has to be done from the iframe and not the parent.

Comment: Can you include some of the source code that shows what you have attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

Within the iframe, you can call a function on the page hosting the iframe:

```
parent.adjustIFrameHeight();
```

Comment: Can you explain more?  I have <script>
    $('#field12593102_1').click(function() {
  parent.adjustIFrameHeight();
});
</script> on the iframe page and then function adjustIFrameHeight(){
$('.childframe').css('height', function(index) {
  return index +=400;})
} on the parent page.  This does not work though.

Comment: which part doesn't work?  do you get an error?  more details please.